# Running pydocs in a external server - Python

Tags: python, pydoc

I have a project which I would like to have it's documentation on a external server.
I know I do `pydoc -p 5000` I will have my documentation on `http://localhost:5000/`. However I'm planning to host that documentation on a EC2 instance, as an external server everyone can access.
Let's say the IP address of the machine is `10.10.10.10`, and it's totally configurable to be access externally.
How can I have `pydoc` to run my server externally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) state:

> Specifying a `-w` flag before the argument will cause HTML documentation to be written out to a file in the current directory, instead of displaying text on the console.

Therefore, use the `-w` flag to write the documentation to files, which you can then copy to your server and have it served as static files. For example, the command `pydoc -w somelib` would write a file `somelib.html` which contained the documentation for `somelib`. Copy that to the root of your server and it would be available at `http://10.10.10.10/somelib.html` (assuming your server is configured correctly).

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be added in version `3.7`.

[Documentation](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc).

Changed in version 3.7: Added the `-n` option.